# TextView added as an item inside a selector -can this be done?

Tags: android, xml, selector

So, as the title states: can I add a TextView inside an item which is in inside a selector?

I will post the code I'v got and comment what I want to achieve.

Note: for the simplcity, going to comment with "//" even though is XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

   <item  android:state_activated="true" 
      android:drawable="@drawable/var0"> 
   </item>

   <item  android:state_activated="false" 
      android:drawable="@drawable/var1"> 
   </item>

  //Here I want the textView to be added ,so that it will be added on top of the other two tings I have got right here^^
  //So I suppose it is an item
  <item>
     //How do I give this item the resource of a textView or perhaps add the textView right here?
  </item>
</selector>
```

Need some guidance through this matter as I did not find much over the internet about this.

Any suggestion is highly appreciated!
If more information is needed ,leave a comment ,although, I cannot link much of the code as I am bound to a confidentiality agreement.

Comment: selector is actually a StateListDrawable and Drawable has no way to add any View inside

Comment: Alright ,so practically, the only way I can get a TextView positioned above this ImageView that gets it's resources from this xml selector ,is to have the imageview inside a relativelayout and get the x and y of the imageview and after that position the textview exactly on those x and y's, right?

Comment: what exactly do you want to do with that ImageView and TextView?

Comment: The ImageView is a Bulblight and I want the TextView to be added inside the Bulblight -in the middle of it (relatively -doesn't have to be exactly there).

The TextView will be displaying the intensity that the bulblight is at.

Anyways,I guess I figured it out.I need to implement this and I will come back with an answer.

Comment: Although, if you have any ideas, let me know -it might be better than my thoughts.

Comment: so use just TextView,  what do you need ImageView for?

Comment: Well, the ImageView is used as button.Therefor,I do need it too.

Comment: use TextView as a button then

Comment: Yea, I could use the TextView as a button ,but it would be A LOT of changes I would have to make.

Anyways, I am trying "my way" ,but most definitely ,using the textView as a button is the right approach.

feel free to give it as an answer and I will mark it as the right one.

Comment: what LOT of changes?  a Button is  a TextView after all...

Comment: Alright,you have a point there.

going to do this as you said.